# Expanding the expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

How to expand:

$E(Y+1)^2$

my working out:

$E(Y^2)+E(1^2) = E(Y^2)+1$ (I'm not sure why this is though..)

Can someone link to or list the rules for expanding the expected value ......

Comment: are you saying $E[(Y+1)^{2}]$ or $(E[Y+1])^{2}$

Comment: the first one...

Comment: what should this expand to in the end do when know anything about Y, Im a little confused what result you want from this other than just rewriting the equation in terms of different properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $(Y+1)^{2}=Y^{2}+2Y+1$ we have 
$$E[(Y+1)^{2}]=E[Y^{2}+2Y+1]$$
where by properties of linear expectation we have
$$=E[Y^{2}]+2E[Y]+1$$
also since $Var[Y]=E[Y^{2}]-(E[Y])^{2}$ we can also write this as
$$=Var[Y]+(E[Y])^{2}+2E[Y]+1$$

Comment: I don't know if this is what you were looking for

Comment: thank you!! so the property is linear expectation